# Quietly stop an application

Tags: erlang

I have some EUnit tests that, as part of their setup/teardown process start and stop some applications.

Any time an application is stopped, Erlang outputs a big log-blob like

```
=INFO REPORT==== 26-Mar-2014::10:43:18 ===
    application: asn1
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
```

The EUnit code I'm using is

```
my_test_() ->
    {setup,
     fun() -> 
         {ok, Apps} = application:ensure_all_started(my_app)
     end,
     fun({ok, AppList}) ->
         lists:foreach(fun (App) -> application:stop(App) end, AppList)
     end,
     [
       ?_test(first_test())
      ,?_test(second_test())
     ]}.
```

This gets me the list of all the applications that got started for my `my_app` application and then that value is passed back to the shutdown function which stops each of those.

Is there anything I can do to keep Erlang quiet about the applications getting shut down? It spews out a lot of text and makes it harder to find output that I care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write:

```
 queit_stop(App) ->
     error_logger:tty(false),
     Res = application:stop(App),
     error_logger:tty(true),
     Res.
```